# d3.js bilevel partition v4 - change children and value function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am currently working on updating the example for a bilevel partition at the link here (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371) to use version 4 of d3.js instead of version 3. Right now I am not worrying about zooming in and out, and only focusing on only showing arcs with a depth of 2 and with the correct values. I have a working JSFiddle where all the arcs are shown here (https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/dgu8Lgpf/) along with the same code below:

```
<!--

    Attempt at converting bilevelpartition to v4

 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

circle,
path {
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

</style>
<body>
</body>
<!-- d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

var data = {
    "name": "root1", 
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "parent1", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "child1", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "leaf1", 
                            "size": 100
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "leaf2", 
                            "size": 200
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "child2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "leaf1",
                            "size": 300
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "leaf2",
                            "size": 400
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {    "name": "parent2", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "child1", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "leaf1", 
                            "size": 100
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "leaf2", 
                            "size": 200
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "child2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "leaf1",
                            "size": 300
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "leaf2",
                            "size": 400
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "parent3", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "child1", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "leaf1", 
                            "size": 100
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "leaf2", 
                            "size": 200
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "child2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "leaf1",
                            "size": 300
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "leaf2",
                            "size": 400
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var width  = 900,
    height = 800,
    radius = ( Math.min( width, height ) / 2 ) - 10;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal( d3.schemeCategory20 );

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",  width  )
            .attr("height", height )
            .append( "g" )
            .attr( "transform", "translate(" + ( width / 2 ) + "," + (height / 2) + ")" );

var partition = d3.partition();

var arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(  function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, Math.min( 2 * Math.PI, x( d.x0 ) ) ); 

    })
    .endAngle(    function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, Math.min( 2 * Math.PI, x( d.x1 ) ) ); 

    })
    .innerRadius( function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, y( d.y0 ) ); 

    })
    .outerRadius( function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, y( d.y1 ) ); 

    });


var root = d3.hierarchy( data );

root.sum( function( d ) 
    { 

        return d.size; 

    })
    .each( function( d )
    {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.overallSum = d.value;
    });

svg.selectAll( "path" )
   .data( partition( root ).descendants( ) )
   .enter()
   .append( "path" )

       .attr( "d", arc )

       .style( "fill", function( d ) 
       { 

           return color( d.data.name ); 

       })
       .append( "title" )

           .text(function( d ) 
           { 

               return d.data.name + "\n" + formatNumber( d.value ); 

           });

</script>
```

In the example that uses version 3, once the data is read in the the initial layout is computed and the children are stored in a new variable for each datum called `._children` and the value is stored inside each datum's `.sum` attribute. The `children` and `value` functions are then reassigned so that `.children` now returns `._children`, but only if a datum has a depth less than 2, and the value function now returns `.sum` for each datum.

```
// Compute the initial layout on the entire tree to sum sizes.
// Also compute the full name and fill color for each node,
// and stash the children so they can be restored as we descend.
partition
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .nodes(root)
    .forEach(function(d) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.sum = d.value;
      d.key = key(d);
      d.fill = fill(d);
    });


// Now redefine the value function to use the previously-computed sum.
partition
    .children(function(d, depth) { return depth < 2 ? d._children : null; })
    .value(function(d) { return d.sum; });
```

For my JSFiddle I am trying to do the equivalent where I am wanting to define the `.children` accessor to return `._children` if a datum has a depth less than 2, and have the value function return `.overallSum`.  However, version 4 of D3 doesn't look like it supports overwriting the 'value' function for a partition or to return only certain children. I am looking for a possible solution so I can return the `._children` variable instead, and overwrite the 'value' function to return `.sum`. Any help will be greatly appreciated, if I need to explain anything else please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var root = d3.hierarchy( data );

/*    
    specifies what each datum should use when a specified datum calls it's 'value'
    function. The node.value property of each node is set to the numeric value 
    returned by the specified function plus the combined value of all descendants.

    https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy
    https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#node_eachAfter
*/    
root.sum( function( d ) 
{ 

    return d.size; 

});

/*
Go through each node and assign the children to the new attribute
._children for each dataum. For all nodes that are one level
below the root set children to null. This allows us to only show
those nodes that are necessary.

https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy
*/
root.each( function ( d )
{
    d._children = d.children;

    if( d.depth >= 1 )
    {
        d.children = null;
    }
});
```

I was able to figure out how to do it.

I looked here (https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) for some guidance and once I go through and calculate the values for each node, I then assign `d._children = d.children` and set `.children` to null if I don't wish to to show it.